# Treat warnings as errors in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

I want to treat warnings as errors in Jenkins, but not when I build locally. So I can't just enable it from the project settings because that would apply locally as well. I also don't want to use a separate configuration, I want to build in Debug for Jenkins.

That leaves specifying it as a command line parameter when running msbuild, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should take a look to the [Warnings Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Plugin) of Jenkins. It is specifically done to parse ("standards") compiler output and group/count warnings. It can also mark your build failed if too many warnings appeared (with the support of the generic [Static Code analysis plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Static+Code+Analysis+Plug-ins)).

You can configure the health of your build according to the number of warnings detected (first line in the following picture). Health will not fail the build, just change the weather associated (sunny, cloudy, rainy... ;) ).

To change the state of the build, this will be done in the last lines of the following picture. In my configuration, if more than 10 warnings are found, builmd will become Unstable, and more than 100 will fail the build. Adjust the values for your needs ;)
Warnings plugin configuration
[image: Warnings plugin configuration]

Comment: I managed to install it, but how do I tell it to fail the build on any warnings? Do I do it from Status thresholds?

Comment: @sashoalm I edited my answer to explain this configuration part

Comment: Thanks. Just to note, I'm using the "check for new warnings" checkbox, which is pretty cool.